# How to Change Mass on Regex

Tags: regex

Before :

```
LIVE | 98.183.227.191:24435 | 0.31 | Virginia | 23517 | ip98-183-227-191.hr.hr.cox.net | United States | Blacklist: No | Checked at http://dichvusocks.us
LIVE | 72.167.179.75:60088 | 1.66 | Arizona | 85260 | ip-50-63-58-100.ip.secureserver.net | United States | Blacklist: No | Checked at http://dichvusocks.us
LIVE | 79.127.124.115:1080 | 1.59 | Unknow | Unknow | 79.127.124.115 | Iran, Islamic Republic of | Blacklist: Yes | Checked at http://dichvusocks.us
LIVE | 89.36.166.204:60088 | 1.68 | Cluj | Unknow | vps.ironmedia.ro | Romania | Blacklist: No | Checked at http://dichvusocks.us
```

After

```
98.183.227.191:24435
72.167.179.75:60088
79.127.124.115:1080
89.36.166.204:60088
```

how to mass clean on Regex ?

Comment: which lang or tool you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `\1`

```
^[^|]*\|\s*(\S+).*
```

OR

```
^[^|]*\|\s*([^|]*?)\s*\|.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK2oE3/4)